# 400 BAD Request when using Spring RestTemplate to POST

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

I try to send the shipping status from my database to ecommerce website, but I get:

> 400 bad request error.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
HashMap orderItems = new HashMap<String, String>();
orderItems.put("id","558443685");
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> orderItemsArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
orderItemsArray.add(orderItems);
HashMap contentOrderFulfillment = new HashMap<String, Object>();
contentOrderFulfillment.put("tracking_number", null);
contentOrderFulfillment.put("line_items",orderItemsArray);
HashMap orderFulfillment = new HashMap<String, Object>();
orderFulfillment.put("fulfillment", contentOrderFulfillment);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("X-ABC-Access-Token", "9a4d5c56a7edf1ac5bb17aa1c");
headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());

MultiValueMap<String, Object> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
requestBody.add("fulfillment", orderFulfillment);
HttpEntity formEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(requestBody, headers);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange("https://mysite.abc.com/admin/orders/406287121/fulfillments.json",HttpMethod.POST,  formEntity,String.class);
System.out.println("Response="+responseEntity.getBody());
```

Answer (score 0):

400 response can be caused from many problems inside your request. Wrong parameters or something like that. Try the request first from command line - with curl or something. When you see it working check if the request from java has the exact same parameters sent.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` (or any descendant) if you extend that handler.

Most of the methods of the handler don't include a message body, so a solution would be for you to extend that class, override the methods handling the exceptions you would like to get an error message for, and provide message body to the `handleExceptionInternal(..)` method.

See also:

- http://www.baeldung.com/2013/01/31/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring-3-2/
- https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc